# what is difference between linq query with Take and without?

Tags: linq, ravendb

I'm new to RavenDB and wonder what is the difference between those two:

With:

```
var cus = _rdb.Session.Query<Customer>().Take(int.MaxValue)  
  .Where(x =>  x.Id != "-3"  );
```

Without:

```
var cus = _rdb.Session.Query<Customer>()  
  .Where(x =>  x.Id != "-3"  );
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Why adding `.Take(int.MaxValue)` should make any sense?

Comment: I have inherited some code which populates grid and this statement Take(int.MaxValue) is everywhere. Not sure yet how raven works but why I would take all documents with querying ravendb? I have notice that omitting this Take also work mostly fine but I'd like to understand the difference.

Comment: Ok, got it. This is the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048943/proper-way-to-retrieve-more-than-128-documents-with-ravendb

Comment: oh, thanks! so without Take I get on 127 records matching where condition.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, you'll get up to 1,024 items.
In the second case, you'll get up to 128 items.

We actively discard the int.MaxValue when you try to use that.